# Handle multiline values with Config::IniFiles

Tags: perl, ini

Is it possible to tell the Config::IniFiles module to treat a multiline-value enclosed in `"` in a way which doesn't cause the whole parsing-process to fail? I have to deal with such an ini-file and unfortunately I can't change any of its content.

This is what it looks like

```
198 revive.msg.fm.email2= "
199 text text text
200 some more text
201 even more text
202
203 and some more"
```

Trying to parse the file with

```
 20 my $cfg_file = Config::IniFiles->new(
 21         -file => '/path/to/config_test.ini',
 22 ) || die Dumper \@Config::IniFiles::errors;
```

gives me

```
$VAR1 = [
    'Line 199 in file /home/zzzpetscript/config_test.ini is mal-formed:
    text text text',
    ...
];
```

I was looking at [`-allowcontinue 0|1`](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/Config-IniFiles-2.82/lib/Config/IniFiles.pm#new_%28_%5B-option=%3Evalue_...%5D_%29), but that only works with trailing `\`, which I can't insert into the file, since I don't have any permissions to change those ini-files that I have to parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CPAN documentation says :

> Multi-line or multi-valued parameters may also be defined ala UNIX
>   "here document" syntax:
>
> ```
> Parameter=<<EOT
> value/line 1
> value/line 2
> EOT
> ```
>
> You may use any string you want in place of "EOT". Note that whatever follows the
>   "<<" and what appears at the end of the text MUST match exactly, including any
>   trailing whitespace.
>
> Alternately, as a configuration option (default is off), continuation
>   lines can be allowed:
>
> ```
> [Section]
> Parameter=this parameter \
>   spreads across \
>   a few lines
> ```
>
> Have you tried either of those? (trying to fudge something else is
>   probably hard work....)

Comment: As I said, I don't have any permissions to change the contents of the ini-file, so I can't add tailing \

Comment: @Vince: Given that Config::IniFiles does not handle the files the way you need it to, you're stuck with either 'choose (write) a different module' or 'hack the current module so it does what you need'. Your ini-files are not in a standard format, it seems, so you probably can't use the standard module for the job. Or, if you're sure they're a standard format, then it isn't one the the module recognizes (but it would be a useful addition to make it work).  The options shown by CodeGorilla should help you find the right parts of the code to change (and guidance on how to add the option).